# Nanogallery2 - tags with spaces

Tags: html, nanogallery

I'd like to have tags with spaces in but I can't appear to do it.  The gallery is working fine and tags partially work but I cant get spaces into them.  My code looks like this (I've also tried it using the tags in the title with a #)

```
<div id="nanogallery2"
// gallery configuration
data-nanogallery2 = '{ 
"thumbnailWidth":   "auto",
"thumbnailHeight":  200,
"itemsBaseURL":     "https://nanogallery2.nanostudio.org/samples/",
"thumbnailLabel":     { "display": "false" },
"galleryFilterTags": true,
"galleryFilterTagsMode": "multiple",
"thumbnailHoverEffect2": "imageScaleIn80",
"allowHTMLinData": "true"
}'
>
<!-- content of the gallery -->
<a href="berlin1.jpg" data-ngtags="first way" data-ngthumb="berlin1t.jpg">Berlin 1 #first</a>
<a href="berlin2.jpg" data-ngtags="second way" data-ngthumb="berlin2t.jpg">Berlin 2 #Second</a>
<a href="berlin3.jpg" data-ngtags="third way" data-ngthumb="berlin3t.jpg">Berlin 3 #Third</a>
</div>
```

Is there a way to add spaces into the tags?  Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Replace spaces with `&nbsp;` inside data-ngtags attributes.

```
<a href="berlin1.jpg" data-ngtags="first&nbsp;way" data-ngthumb="berlin1t.jpg">Berlin 1 #first</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Open jquery.nanogallery2.js and jquery.nanogallery2.core.js files and

find & replace

```
item.setTags(tags.split(' '));
```

to

```
item.setTags(tags.split(','));
```